# Contiguious dynamic memory allocation in linked list

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, allocation, contiguous

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node* next;
} node;

node* fi = NULL, *la = NULL, *ptr;

void insertfi()
{
    ptr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("\nEnter info\n");
    scanf("%d", &ptr->info);
    ptr->next = fi;
    if (fi == NULL && la == NULL)
    {
        fi = la = ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        fi = ptr;
    }
}

void print()
{
    ptr = fi;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("|%d|-->", ptr->info);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i, ch;
    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter your choice \n1.insert node\n2.view node\n3.exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        if (ch == 1)
        {
            insertfi();
        }
        else if (ch == 2)
        {
            print();
        }
        else
            printf("Exiting\n");
    } while (ch != 3);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to save space in a program that I am working on. This program creates nodes and joins them by storing address of the node in the next pointer in the structure.
I want some way to not use the *next pointer to go to the next node - if I do this I will be able to save 2 bytes of memory.

I have been thinking if there is a way of contiguous allocation of address in dynamic memory allocation, so that I will store the address of the first node in a pointer then traverse or do whatever with it after tinkering with the address.

And how do addresses work - I mean how can I access them by inputting an address in the pointer 
and then printing it?

Here is a sample program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    int a[10],i,*ptr;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        a[i]=rand()%15;
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%6x\n",&a[i]);
    }
    ptr=&a[0];
    printf("\n\n\n%d\n",*ptr);

}
```

It prints addresses in a contiguous manner but I don't know how to allocate them manually, like ptr=0022ff04 and then using `printf("%d",*ptr);

---

```
#include<conio.h>

#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

#include<string.h>

#include<stdbool.h>

#define max 20

typedef struct node
{
    int info;
    int row;
    int colum;
    struct node *next;
}node;

node *ptr,*fi=NULL,*la=NULL;

int r,c,i,j,sparse[max][max],decompmatx[max][max];

void makenode(int getrow,int getcolum,int getinfo)

{
ptr=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
ptr->next=NULL;
if(fi==NULL)
{
    ptr->info=getinfo;
    ptr->row=getrow;
    ptr->colum=getcolum;
    fi=la=ptr;  
}
else
{
    la->next=ptr;
    la=ptr;
    ptr->info=getinfo;
    ptr->row=getrow;
    ptr->colum=getcolum;
}

}

void decompress()

{
int temp;
temp=0;
ptr=fi;
while(ptr!=NULL)
{
    decompmatx[ptr->row][ptr->colum]=ptr->info;
    ptr=ptr->next;
}
for(i=0;i<=r-1;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<=c-1;j++)
        {
            if(decompmatx[i][j]>0)
            {

            }
            else
            decompmatx[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
printf("\nValue decompressed\n");
for(i=0;i<r;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<c;j++)
    printf("%d  ",decompmatx[i][j]);
    if((temp%c)==0)
    printf("\n");
    else
    temp++;

}

}

void showsparse()

{
int temp;
temp=0;
for(i=0;i<r;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<c;j++)
    printf("%d  ",sparse[i][j]);
    if((temp%c)==0)
    printf("\n");
    else
    temp++;

}

}

void print()

{
ptr=fi;
while(ptr!=NULL)
{
    printf("|%d|%d||%d|--->",ptr->info,ptr->row,ptr->colum);
    ptr=ptr->next;
}   


}

int main()

{
int ch;
do
{
printf("\nInput choice\n1.Make Sparse Matrix\n2.compress Matrix\n3.Decompress 
Matrix\n4.Exit...");
scanf("%d",&ch);
if(ch==1)
{
    printf("Input the rows\n");
    scanf("%d",&r);
    printf("Enter colum\n");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    printf("Printing the %dx%d matrix\n",r,c);
    for(i=0;i<=r-1;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<=c-1;j++)
        {
            sparse[i][j]=rand()%2;
        }
    }
    showsparse();
    printf("\nTotal Byte comsuming is =%d\n",r*c*2);
}
else if(ch==2)
{
    for(i=0;i<=r-1;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<=c-1;j++)
        {
            if(sparse[i][j]!=0)
            {
                makenode(i,j,sparse[i][j]);
            }

        }
    }
    printf("Data compressed\n");
    print();
    printf("size of node =%d",sizeof(node));

}
else if(ch==3)
{
    decompress();   
}

else
{
    printf("\nExiting..............\n");
}
}while(ch!=4);

getch();


}
```

Comment: There's no way you can specifically set an address for `malloc`. You may *suggest* the OS to give you some space starting at an address of your choice via `mmap` for example, but it's never under your control simply because your desired address may belong to someone else (the OS, another process etc) in the first place.

Comment: You can allocate an array of pointers (so, of type `node **`), taking care to resize the array as needed

Comment: i want to store multiple ints in my program so i need a structure there should be some way as my seniors have made that possible.....

Comment: Create a static int array of very large size maybe with malloc or define one. Big enough to hold everything.    Are you worrried about locality or numa issues?  Really large blobs of data do not fit into cpu caches very well, so what you need to get is a complete understanding about is your system's cache architecture. First.  Then worry about writing code second.

Comment: actually i want to make a image compressing program by opening an image in 2d array in binary form and then storing the non null positions in linked list if an image is like 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 then i will only store the ones in an 1 bit integer defined in a structure... the elements will be row colum and 1 integer if i use this approach image compression rate will be higher ......

Answer (score 0):

The following was already suggested by jim mcnamara and japreiss in comments.

Instead of dynamic allocation, use a pool of preallocated objects. For example:

```
node my_pool = malloc(10000 * sizeof(pool));
```

Then replace the pointer by an array index:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int info;
    int next_index;
} node;
```

So instead using pointers, you can now use array indices. Why is this good?

- You can be sure that your objects are allocated in contiguous memory (this improves cache locality and ultimately improves performance)
- You can reduce the size of your objects e.g. using `uint16_t` for your index (even uint32_t will give improvement, if you are using a 64-bit platform)
- If `malloc` wastes memory by storing management/debugging data, you are going to improve it
- Allocating data in an array is faster than using `malloc`
- If you don't care when deallocation happens, you can deallocate all objects at once: `free(my_pool)`

Of course, nothing is good unconditionally. Using a pool has disadvantages (e.g. it wastes memory that could be used for other purposes).

Comment: disadvantage is the whole problem of this approach i want to use limited memory for my image compression program i have commented on the upper post about my image procesing program i will be using bitwise operator i will post a prototype of the program take a look at that u guys will be able to provide more assistance about the program then.....

Comment: and in this case space complexity is the main motive time can be increased  still it will be very less while compressing an image considering todays cpus.....